# Angular download SQLite file

Tags: angular, sqlite, blob

I have this code which is downloading a file from server, and its working for most of the files except of SQLite *.db file

```
download(node){
    this.service.downloadFile(node.data.path)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => this.saveToFileSystem(response, node.data.name));    
}

private saveToFileSystem(response, filename) {
    const blob = new Blob([response._body], { /*type: 'application/octet-stream'*/ });
    saveAs(blob ,filename);
}
```

The *.db file is being downloaded to my computer but when opening it getting:

[image]

I tried both, with/without: type: 'application/octet-stream'

Comment: Try comparing the files (e.g., with a checksum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'm downloading file, maybe that will help you:
Component:

```
this._service.export(column, date)
       .subscribe(
           (data) => { this.openFileForDownload(data);},
           error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error;  },
           () => {  });

openFileForDownload(data: HttpResponse<any>) {
        let filename = data.headers.get('filename');
        saveAs(data.body, filename);}
```

service:

```
export(column: string, date: Date) {
        let params = new HttpParams()
            .append('column', column)
            .append('date', date ? date.toISOString() : '')
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
        return this._http.get<any>(url, { headers: headers, params: params, responseType: 'blob' as 'json', observe: 'response' as 'body' });
    }
```

Comment: I updated the get call in my service to: return this.http.get(url ,{responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}) and it worked.

Comment: @zbeedatm I'm glad to able to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Worked when I updated the get call in my service to this.http.get(url ,**{responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}**):

```
downloadFile(path){      
    var url = this.fileBrowseUrl + "download?path=" + path.replace(/\\/g,"%5C");

    return this.http.get(url ,{responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
    .do(/*this.showSpinner = true*/)
    .catch((response: Response) => this.errorHandler(response) );
}
```